# Trying to rout https to http on wordpress but its its not working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Greeting all.

i am trying to route https://example.com to http://example.com

The SSL certificate has been removed and the website is loosing its Google rank as its trying to open https links and getting "This site can’t provide a secure connection" errors.

Tried many things but could not find the solution.

Here is the htacess file code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any Help ?

Comment: it is not a htaccess problem goto your theme and check there should be a static link using https . change it to only http

Comment: have you replace the url from database ?

Comment: there are no static https links. all i want is if someone types https://example.com in the browser the user should be redirected to http://example.com @AnkitMishra

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `header.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
    $url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: there are no static links. i just want the user to redirect to http website if user types in the https link in the browser